# Symfony: extra field to a form not saved

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

OK, I have one form with another embedded form. In actions.php I have:

```
...
// add extra field - select for dynamic population
$tempFrm = new SbCarteOpTempForm(array(), array('type' => 'transfer'));
$tempFrm->setWidget('inv_selectate',new sfWidgetFormSelectMany(array('choices' => array())));
$tempFrm->setValidator('inv_selectate', new sfValidatorPass());

$tempFrm->setWidget('status',new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(),array('value'=>'pending')));
$tempFrm->setValidator('status', new sfValidatorPass());
```

The extra fields "inv_selectate" and "status" should be included in displayed form, and they are indeed. But when I try to submit form, only status variable is sent, the select element is not (inv_selectate).

Why is this happening? I really don't see the problem (and neither the difference between these two new added fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Weird. If I try with a sfWidgetFormSelect instead of sfWidgetFormSelectMany it works. Hmm...

Comment: Could you post your template here?

Comment: The template is something like this (just plain echo form) http://pastebin.com/m33e0c2b7

Answer (score 1):

I found it :)

It's related to the select element. Inside the template I use js to add elements to it (dynamically populated by user), but the select won't appear in form submission unless you have **some elements selected** within!

In my case the selected has only elements, none selected. D'oh! :)

Comment: if you need to ensure there is always a value, you could try creating a custom widget that contains a select and a hidden widget (take a look at how sfWidgetFormDateRange works - you can copy it, it does something similar with two sfWidgetFormDate objects)